# Can I establish more than 1 TCP connections to same server on same port from same single client? Specifically to port 445

Tags: windows, tcp

Can I establish more than 1 TCP connections to same server on same port ?
For example :

> Connection 1: machine A to Machine B on port 445
>
> Connection 2: machine A to Machine B on port 445

Without terminating previously established connection 1.
If yes, do i need to do any setting to enable such scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Without any special setting.

That's exactly what happens when you start, let's say Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox and navigate to the same site with both.

Behind the scene to connect to the server, machine A opens a socket using whatever port number and tries to connect to machine B port 445. Machine B, who was listening on port 445 can accept this incoming connection, and uses another socket using whatever other port number to connect it to. In the end, the actual TCP connection is established between whatever port en machine A and whatever port on machine B. On machine B, port 445 is left for listening only (and can accept other connections).

Comment: Thanks, Actually port 445 is for resource sharing in windows. Once connection established. I am unable to establish another connection until i disconnect previous connection. I am working on application(.Net C#) which access remote machine user detail using Directoryentry(.Net class) object. In this connection gets established  to port 445 and it is not getting release, but i am unable to establish new connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, a TCP/IP session is identified by the following 5-tuple:

```
(src-ip, src-port, dst-ip, dst-port, protocol).
```

In your case, 4 of the 5 values have to be the same: `src-ip (A), dst-ip (B), dst-port (445), protocol (tcp)`. As such, the `src-port` still gives you a degree of freedom, by variating this, you can set up multiple sessions. This is what should happen by default, your OS will select a new, unique source port for each connection to the same server.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP standard supports this with [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). You connect to fixed port on server side, but port on client side is not under your control. TCP/IP stack will choose client port, and connection is then defined and distinguished from other connections with 4 bits of information: client IP address, client port, server IP address, and server port.

Comment: in most implementations you DO have the possibility to control the port used for the connection, it's just not required to do so (or in general even recommended).

Comment: Yes, better wording could be "by default not under your control". I just didn't want to add noise to the answer.